# next and previous post link ordered alphabetically

Tags: order, next-post-link, previous-post-link

I found a [snippet](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/166932/how-to-get-next-and-previous-post-links-alphabetically-by-title-across-post-ty), which order all posts alphabetically. I wonder if is there a way to make it working just for one post-type? I have some custom post type in my website, and i want one of them to be ordered alphabetically, but the rest by date.

I changed `filter_next_post_sort` and `fiter_previous_post_sort` like this:

```
function filter_next_post_sort($sort) {
  if (get_post_type($post) == 'MyCustomPostType') {
    $sort = "ORDER BY p.post_title ASC LIMIT 1";
  }
  else{
    $sort = "ORDER BY p.post_date ASC LIMIT 1";
  }
  return $sort;
}
```

I hope it's good like that.
But i need to change `filter_next_post_where` and `filter_previous_post_where` as well, but i don't find the right way.

Now they look like this:

```
function filter_next_post_where($where) {
    global $post, $wpdb;
    return $wpdb->prepare("WHERE p.post_title > '%s' AND p.post_type = '". get_post_type($post)."' AND p.post_status = 'publish'",$post->post_title);
}

function filter_previous_post_where($where) {
    global $post, $wpdb;
    return $wpdb->prepare("WHERE p.post_title < '%s' AND p.post_type = '". get_post_type($post)."' AND p.post_status = 'publish'",$post->post_title);
}
```

Any suggestion, what to change? Thanks!

EDITED: I tried this, but it's not working:

```
function filter_next_post_where($where) {
    global $post, $wpdb;
    if (get_post_type($post) == 'szinesz') {
        return $wpdb->prepare("WHERE p.post_title > '%s' AND p.post_type = '". get_post_type($post)."' AND p.post_status = 'publish'",$post->post_title);
    }
    else{
        return $wpdb->prepare("WHERE p.post_date > '%s' AND p.post_type = '". get_post_type($post)."' AND p.post_status = 'publish'",$post->post_title);
    }
}
```

Oh, and i use WP 4.1.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the solution.
The whole snippet looks like this:

```
<?php
function filter_next_post_sort($sort) {
    global $post;
    if (get_post_type($post) == 'MyCustomPostType') {
        $sort = "ORDER BY p.post_title ASC LIMIT 1";
    }
    else{
        $sort = "ORDER BY p.post_date ASC LIMIT 1";
    }
    return $sort;
}
function filter_next_post_where($where) {
    global $post, $wpdb;
    if (get_post_type($post) == 'MyCustomPostType') {
        return $wpdb->prepare("WHERE p.post_title > '%s' AND p.post_type = '". get_post_type($post)."' AND p.post_status = 'publish'",$post->post_title);
    }
    else{
        return $wpdb->prepare( "WHERE p.post_date > '%s' AND p.post_type = '". get_post_type($post)."' AND p.post_status = 'publish'", $post->post_date);
    }
}

function filter_previous_post_sort($sort) {
    global $post;
    if (get_post_type($post) == 'MyCustomPostType') {
        $sort = "ORDER BY p.post_title DESC LIMIT 1";
    }
    else{
        $sort = "ORDER BY p.post_date DESC LIMIT 1";
    }
    return $sort;
}
function filter_previous_post_where($where) {
    global $post, $wpdb;
    if (get_post_type($post) == 'MyCustomPostType') {
        return $wpdb->prepare("WHERE p.post_title < '%s' AND p.post_type = '". get_post_type($post)."' AND p.post_status = 'publish'",$post->post_title);
    }
    else{
        return $wpdb->prepare( "WHERE p.post_date < '%s' AND p.post_type = '". get_post_type($post)."' AND p.post_status = 'publish'", $post->post_date);
    }
}

add_filter('get_next_post_sort',   'filter_next_post_sort');
add_filter('get_next_post_where',  'filter_next_post_where');

add_filter('get_previous_post_sort',  'filter_previous_post_sort');
add_filter('get_previous_post_where', 'filter_previous_post_where');
```

Comment: This solution is broken. You need to delete the references to `$post->post_type` and you need to add the globals to every four of your functions. I wanted to use your example and php output some errors, so I fixed them. If someone wants a revised code, I can add it, but I think it would just be better to edit this solution, as it is already marked as sufficient.

Comment: This doesn't allow for excluded terms.