# Taxonomy terms sort by... Last name!

Tags: taxonomy

I have a custom Taxonomy named 'authors' where I insert additional authors.
My question is: is it possible to list all the taxonomy terms order by "Last Name".
If I order by name clearly it looks like:

- Andrea Red
- Daniel Green
- Elena Blue

Instead of this I would like to sort by Last Name:

- Elena Blue
- Daniel Green
- Andrea Red

Do you have any advice to do it? Is it better to add a New Custom Field in Custom Taoxnomy where I specify the Last Name and then I sort by that term?

Thank you very much

Elena

Comment: Duplicate of [WordPress Orderby Last Word In Title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416217/wordpress-orderby-last-word-in-title)? Anyway, you can change the query like so: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_orderby

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the MySQL function [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) within the `get_terms_orderby` filter:

```
/**
 * Order by the last word in the term name
 * @link https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/195039/26350
 */
add_filter( 'get_terms_orderby', function( $orderby, $args )
{
    if( isset( $args['orderby'] ) && 'wpse_last_word' === $args['orderby'] )  
        $orderby = " SUBSTRING_INDEX( t.name, ' ', -1 ) ";
    return $orderby;
}, 10, 2 );
```

to order by the *last word* in the *term name*.

Here we activate the *last-word* ordering through our custom `wpse_last_word` argument:

```
$terms = get_terms( 'category', [ 'orderby' => 'wpse_last_word' ] );
```

You can also add the `wpse_last_word` argument, through the `get_terms_args` filter, if you need to override some term query.

I recently used this method [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/194605/26350) for posts.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you @Elena

Comment: @Elena you should accept this answer as it seemed to have worked for you;-). Look for the checkmark next to the answer and click on it, it will go green. Done. ;-) To help you, please see [what should I do when someone answers my question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Oooh I'm sorry @birgire! I'm new here and I don't know exactly what to do! Thanks for the advice @PieterGoosen! :)

Comment: Hey, I'm working on a similar situation and this solution is very nearly perfect. Any idea how to exclude suffixes (Jr, Sr, II, etc.) so that they are never used for the alphabetization?

Comment: @JoshM maybe my [answer here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/216944/26350) can help or the others there.